# Run 'change' function from another element

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a function that runs when  a checkbox is changed (works fine):

```
// event management
$("input.box[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    $("input:checkbox[name='$name']").attr("checked", true);
    $.cookie(name, $(this).prop('checked'), {
        path: '/',
        expires: 365
    });
});
```

```html
<input id="<?php echo the_ID();?>" type="checkbox" name="<?php echo the_ID();?>">
```

I also want to be able to change the state of the checkbox from another button:

```
<a onclick="$('#<?php echo the_ID();?>').attr('checked', true);">test</a>
```

This does change the checkbox but does not run the change function.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: add `.trigger('change')`

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered, setting the `checked` attribute programmatically does not fire any events. You can do this manually using `change()`:

```html
<a onclick="$('#<?php echo the_ID();?>').attr('checked', true).change();">test</a>
```

Note that `trigger('change')` would work too.